# What is "lrelease"?

Tags: windows, pepper

I am trying to make a naoqi package with qipkg (I dont know if this problem is specific to aldebaran naoqi or if it is a general windows problem)

> qipkg make-package Pepper-Demo.pml

but I get the folowing error:

> NotInPath Could not find executable: lrelease

qipkg deploy-package is working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the folowing steps:

Check if there is a .exe file called lrelease in the folder at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Softbank Robotics\Choregraphe Suite 2.5\bin
If not, search for the file on your computer using search in file explorer.

The error message displayed in which folders it searched for.
Go to the first folder it searched in (or create it) and paste the lrelease file.